# What is best practise for loading partial views in MVC without js caching?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I' am working on a ASP NET MVC project where pages are loaded like partial views with a lot of js code, and the problem is that on every load of partial view js script, which is in an separated file, is also loaded and cached in the browser. Is there any elegant and clean way for avoiding such a behavior?

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? Are those script files in your layout?

Comment: Script files are individually loaded into the partial views, on the Layout itself I have only loaded scripts needed in whole project. When I load them into partial view, as a consequence of script caching pages loses functionality after loading different partial views one after another.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the usual way is to append a querystring to the url, like ?v=2138908934890, where the number is the current date, from new Date().getTime(). This prevents the browser from retrieving the cached file.